# "onLocationChanged" callback is never called (flutter_osm_plugin) but the gps localization is working

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to build a Flutter app which needs to update its internal state every time the user change position. To do so, I have installed flutter_osm_plugin and I have created widget OSMFlutter which has "trackMyPosition" set to True and also has "onLocationChanged" set to a function.

Every time the user moves I have to refresh the markers on the map, and as stated in the documentation:
`onLocationChanged: (callback) it is fired when you activate tracking and user position has been changed`
but the things is that it doesn't work, it will run just one time when the map is loaded. I'm sure that the gelocalization permissions are working because the user is correctly placed on the map, and when the user moves the marker on the map moves, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I actually don't need to use the "onLocationChanged" provided with the package, I just need to run a function when the user moves so I can fetch new data from my database. Has anyone else encountered this problem? How can I solve it? Here's my code:

manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

the widget (in this example I'm just trying to increment a counter to see if it will update on the screen)

```
OSMFlutter( 
    controller: controller,
    trackMyPosition: true,
    initZoom: 12,
    minZoomLevel: 8,
    maxZoomLevel: 19,
    stepZoom: 1.0,
    onLocationChanged: (p0) => setState(() {
          _counter++;
        }),
    onGeoPointClicked:(p0) => print("test" + p0.toString()),
    userLocationMarker: UserLocationMaker(
    personMarker: const MarkerIcon(
        icon: Icon(
            Icons.location_history_rounded,
            color: Colors.red,
            size: 100,
            ),
        ),
    directionArrowMarker: const MarkerIcon(
        icon: Icon(
                Icons.double_arrow,
                size: 48,
                ),
            ),
        ),
     roadConfiguration: const RoadOption(
                roadColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
        ),
     markerOption: MarkerOption(
         defaultMarker: const MarkerIcon(
             icon: Icon(
                  Icons.person_pin_circle,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  size: 56,
                  ),
                )
)
```

Thanks to anyone that can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this issue: https://github.com/liodali/osm_flutter/issues/339

I also found this: https://github.com/liodali/osm_flutter/issues/243 with the solution to set the isPicker flag to true, but tbh. i dont know why this should fix the problem.

Since you only want to know when your position changes, you can also use the [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) package (Flutter Favorite).

There you can easily query for position changes by implementing the PositionStream.

```
final LocationSettings locationSettings = LocationSettings(
  accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
  distanceFilter: 100,
);
StreamSubscription<Position> positionStream = Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: locationSettings).listen(
    (Position? position) {
        print(position == null ? 'Unknown' : '${position.latitude.toString()}, ${position.longitude.toString()}');
    });
```

Comment: The geolocator solution is working fine but I have one more problem. When declaring positionStream, I can't put inside the listener a call to setState() because "The instance member 'setState' can't be accessed in an initializer.". I tried splitting the definition and defining on the line below the "ondata" behaviour but it doesn't work. I also tried adding the "late" keyword to do a late initialization but the listener doesn't work anymore. How can I call setState inside the listener? btw thanks so much for fixing my problem, that library seems pretty unmaintained but it shows the map fine

Comment: I would initialize it in the initState, you can call setState inside it